# How to correctly add propTypes to a React component in ES6?

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing my React component as a ES6 class. I tried to add `propTypes` and Meteor threw this error `A semicolon is required after a class property`. Here's my component :

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  propTypes: {
    content: React.PropTypes.element
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    $(window).load(() => {
      $('.flexslider')
      .flexslider(
        { animation: 'fade', animationSpeed: 1500, controlNav: false }
      );
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        {/* Content */}
        { this.props.content }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With es6 class synax, you cannot set static properties on classes in the class definition.

So basically, instead of

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  propTypes: {
    content: React.PropTypes.element
  }
  ..
}
```

it should be

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  ...
}

MainLayout.propTypes = {
  content: React.PropTypes.element
}
```

With es7 classes, you can define proptypes like this, however, which is more in line with what you'd expect:

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    content: React.PropTypes.element
  }
  ..
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! But What if I define it as a static function inside the class definition like this   `static propTypes () {
    return {
      content: React.PropTypes.element,
    };
  }` ?

Comment: I suspect it would throw an error since `propTypes` needs to be an object

Comment: I just tried and it actually worked. But not sure whether it's the right way

Comment: Done some more testing... it does not throw any errors but it doesn't work. Won't do the validation... Your method works perfectly :-)

Comment: Inside the class, `static get propTypes() {
    return {
      ...
    }
  }` worked for me.